# Why does OpenGL 3+ throws viewing matrices manipulation away?

Tags: opengl, glsl, jogl

GL version 1 and 2 contain functions manipulating the model, view and projection matrices, such as "glLoadIdentity()" and etc. And glu is usually used together to set the camera and viewing perspective.

However, GL version 3+ does not support those any more, which means you have to implement those instead. But I don't see any advantages of doing that. I'm using JOGL, and I found many sample code doing that with CPU, which I think has even lower performance. Any ideas about that?

Now I'm using PMVMatrix library to replace glu's work. Are there any differences between these two libraries? Or any better choices?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One important consideration that people often forget is that OpenGL is not designed to be a convenient interface for programmers. It is designed to provide an abstraction of graphics hardware.

Of course not all GPUs have exactly the same features, but they mostly tend to be fairly similar. And manipulating matrices in the way necessary for the old style matrix management functionality is just not a feature that would make sense for a GPU to support.

GPUs are mostly SIMD (Single Instruction, Multiple Data) machines. This means that they are really good at performing the same operations on a lot of data in parallel. In the classic rendering pipeline, this means processing many vertices in parallel by running the same vertex shader on all of them, and processing many fragments in parallel by running the same fragment shader on all of them.

For matrix stack manipulations, the corresponding operations are only executed once. CPUs are much more efficient at doing this. Also, the operations are very cheap, so executing them on the CPU is really not a performance concern.

Even in the legacy pipeline, these operations would typically be executed on the CPU. The only thing that really changed is that they are now left up to the app code, where they were previously in the driver code.

Since OpenGL is optimized for hardware abstraction and not for convenience, the idea is that higher level libraries can provide more convenient interface. In this case, one of the many available matrix libraries can provide implementations of this functionality for you.